# how to install tensorflow on window with anaconda

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

OS : window 7 64 bit 
anaconda version is 4.3
I try to install tensorflow using anaconda.

First I installed anaconda.
The second,

> conda creat -n tensorflow

Third, the environment is not activated.
If you type activate tensorflow, it says that it is not a cmd command.
Can not you just type

> activate tensorflow

into anaconda prompt?

Where should I enter 'activate tensorflow'?

Comment: Is Window a cheaper version of Windows that only allows to have one window open at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `creat` use `create`

```
 conda create -n tensorflow

 activate tensorflow
```